# Ember CLI + Watchman Not Detecting Addon Changes

Tags: ember.js, watchman, ember-addon

I have an Ember.js addon which Watchman does not seem to operate correctly with. Any changes made to the *addon-name/app* files **do not** trigger a rebuild. However, changes to files within *addon-name/tests* do trigger a rebuild.

I have a .watchmanconfig file set up as follows...

```
{
  "ignore_dirs": [ "tmp", "dist", ".idea", "docs", ".git", "node_modules" ]
}
```

After running the dummy app with *ember s*, I checked *watchman watch-list* and do not see the addon listed in the "roots" category. I've added it manually, but that does not help either, as I'm guessing *ember s* has to tell watchman what to do when the files are changed.

Any ideas on what might be happening?

```
OS: Mac OSX High Sierra (10.13.4)
Ember: v3.1.0
Node: v8.11.1
NPM: 6.0.0
Yarn: 1.5.1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using symlink then some times watchman does not track the changes, to track your changes in your addon's index.js add following code

```
module.exports = {
  name: projectName,
  isDevelopingAddon: true
};
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunately, watchman doesn't recognize changes even when serving the dummy app (no symlink-ing involved). I've added this code just in case, but the problem still persists. By the way, the correct code is `isDevelopingAddon: () => true;` for those needing the symlink fix.